# how can I insert a table in a XWPFTableCell with NPOI?

Tags: .net, cpu-word, npoi

I was trying to use NPOI to create a word document from a template.Inside the document I was trying to insert a table in a table cell.The table cell has two paragraphs, I was trying to insert a table between the two paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:
In the template, create a table between the two paragraphs to replace.

```
        CT_Tbl tbl = new CT_Tbl();
        int index = cell.GetCTTc().Items.IndexOf(cell.Tables[0].GetCTTbl());
        cell.GetCTTc().Items.RemoveAt(index);
        cell.GetCTTc().Items.Insert(index, tbl);
        int rowCount = dtData.Rows.Count;
        int columnCount = dtData.Columns.Count;
        XWPFTable xTable = new XWPFTable(tbl, body, rowCount, columnCount);
```